# Line is detected as diagonal of rectangle while using collidepoint function in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-development, pygame2

I am working on a graph based project. I am drawing lines to represent the edges. My goal is to change color of line when I click on the specific line. the problem is pygame treats line as diagonal of virtual rectangle. so when even if I don't click on the line but the mouse position is in the projected area of the virtual rectangle, the event is detected as collision while using collidepoint(). I want to detect this only when the mouse is clicked on actual line only.

I am new to pygame, so let me know if there is other function or library that I can use. This is the example code of my project.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,700))

running = True
red = 0
green = 255
blue = 210

while running:
   screen.fill((red,green,blue))
    line = pygame.draw.line(screen, green, (50,50), (400,400),10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if line.collidepoint(event.pos):
                red = 255
                green = 0
                blue = 0
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            red = 0
            green = 255
            blue = 210

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.draw.line`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) returns a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object that defines the axis aligned bounding rectangle surrounding the line. [`collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) test if a point is in a rectangle.

---

You have to use a different approach. Write a function that computes the shortest distance of a point to a line:

*`dist = abs(dot(normalized(NV), P - LP))`*, where *`NV`* is the normal vector to the line, *`LP`* is a point on the line and *`P`* is the point whose distance needs to be calculated.

```py
import math
```

```py
def distance_point_line(pt, l1, l2):
    nx, ny = l1[1] - l2[1], l2[0] - l1[0]
    nlen = math.hypot(nx, ny)
    nx /= nlen
    ny /= nlen
    vx, vy = pt[0] - l1[0],  pt[1] - l1[1]
    dist = abs(nx*vx + ny*vy)
    return dist
```

The same function with the use of [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2):

```py
def distance_point_line(pt, l1, l2):
    NV = pygame.math.Vector2(l1[1] - l2[1], l2[0] - l1[0])
    LP = pygame.math.Vector2(l1)
    P = pygame.math.Vector2(pt)
    return abs(NV.normalize().dot(P -LP))
```

Test whether the mouse pointer is in the rectangle defined by the line and whether the distance is less than half the line width:

```py
if (line_rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and 
    distance_point_line(event.pos, (50,50), (400,400)) < 5):
    # [...]
```

---

Explanation:

I've used the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) distance from the point to the line.. In general The Dot product of 2 vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors multiplied by the magnitude (length) of both vectors.

```
dot( A, B ) == | A | * | B | * cos( angle_A_B )
```

This follows, that the Dot product of 2 [Unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors, because the length of a unit vector is 1.

```
uA = normalize( A )
uB = normalize( B )
cos( angle_A_B ) == dot( uA, uB )
```

[image]

Therefore the Dot product of the normalized normal vector to the line (*NV*) and a vector from a point on the line (*LP*)  to the point whose distance must be calculated (*P*) is the shortest distance of the point to the line.

[image]

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,700))

def distance_point_line(pt, l1, l2):
    NV = pygame.math.Vector2(l1[1] - l2[1], l2[0] - l1[0])
    LP = pygame.math.Vector2(l1)
    P = pygame.math.Vector2(pt)
    return abs(NV.normalize().dot(P -LP))

color = (255, 255, 255)
running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    line_rect = pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (50,50), (400,400), 10)
    pygame.display.update()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
            if (line_rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and 
                distance_point_line(event.pos, (50,50), (400,400)) < 5):
                color = (255, 0, 0)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            color = (255, 255, 255)
```